# Regex urlconf in django 1.8 won't work

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Why does this work?

```
url(r'^polls/', include('pollapp.urls'))
```

But this not?

```
url(r'^(polls/)|(pollapp/)', include('pollapp.urls'))
```

I am following the tutorial polls app and wanted to route to the detail page using either polls/1/ or pollapp/1/

There has to be something I am missing maybe concerning regex?

Answer (score 2):

Your patterns are not working because such patterns break the Django's [reverse url resolution](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls)  functionality.

Reversing urls takes a view and it's params and determines what url which that view has. With patterns like your `(polls/)|(pollapp/)` Django is unable to tell which version of the url you want. Should it be `/polls/yourview` or `/pollapp/yourview` ?

Two fix that you could include both patterns in your urlconfig:

```
url(r'^polls/', include('pollapp.urls')),
url(r'^pollapp/', include('pollapp.urls')),
```

However i strongy advice to chose only pattern (`polls` or `pollsapp`) to keep your code simple and avoid duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt isn't a valid regex for matching what you want. Try something like:

```
url(r'^poll(s|app)/', include('pollapp.urls'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just:

```
url(r'^polls/', include('pollapp.urls')),
url(r'^pollapp/', include('pollapp.urls')),
```

Then both `polls/` and `pollapp/` will work.

You can't have both in one url as Django won't know which to reverse in some situations.